# Prevent PC from using Wifi over Ethernet to access Synology NAS

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ethernet, nas, synology-diskstation

Im having a small issue that I thought would be easy to solve but is proving difficult. I have a synology nas connected to a router via Ethernet. My PC (Win10) connects to the NAS via ethernet and to the router via a wifi adapter.

For some reason, it never uses the ethernet connection to access the content on the NAS, even if its struggling to stream the video. If I disconnect the wifi, it will use the ethernet connection. I have tried turning File and printer sharing off in the adapter settings but this hasnt worked, possibly because the NAS is using SMB not FTP protocol? I have also assigned manual network priority numbers through powershell to favour Ethernet (It was favoured by default), but this hasnt worked either.

Any suggestions? I want the wifi adapter to connect to the internet only, and not be able to connect to the NAS, that way its always NAS ==> Ethernet ===> PC for the fastest most consistent connection.

Comment: Are you positive both of your adapters are connected?  By default Windows 10 is supposed to prefer an Ethernet adapter over a Wireless adapter, which means by default, you cannot use the other adapter without a very simple priority hack.  Have you tried to map the network location after you changed the priority numbers?  I presume the internet network is separate from the network that contains the NAS?

Comment: yes both adapters are connected. Im guessing because the ethernet is not connected to the network, its only a link between the PC and NAS, that maybe windows doesnt see it as an active network. It comes up as "unidentified network, no internet access", but it can access the NAS just fine. The NAS is connected to the same router as the wifi adapter, so they are both on the same network. I will try your suggestion to map after priority change.

Comment: Any help on this?